# VBA Sumifs under two conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a function that will sum up for me

```
CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN = "CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN"
CRD_KOR_DC_FIN = "CRD_KOR_DC_FIN"
```

When two conditions are met, where DIFFRENT> 365 and CRD_RWG <1.5
However, my macro shows me a result of 0. Where do I go wrong?

```
Set wbMe = ActiveWorkbook
CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN = "CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN"
CRD_KOR_DC_FIN = "CRD_KOR_DC_FIN"
DIFFRENT = "DIFFRENT"
CRD_RWG = "CRD_RWG"
With wbMe.Sheets("NPE")
If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=DIFFRENT, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set rCol1 = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set rCol2 = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=CRD_KOR_DC_FIN, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set rCol3 = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=CRD_RWG, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
        .Range("T39").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), ">365", rTable.Columns(rCol3.Column), "<1.5", rTable.Columns(rCol1.Column), "CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN", rTable.Columns(rCol2.Column), "CRD_KOR_DC_FIN")
    End If
End With
```

My date :

[image]

Comment: First suggestion: try adding the conditions one by one to your formula to see which of them work or don't work. (Your table does contain data that matches, right?) You have two different assignments to rCol, is that right?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins yes its my fault, but still same after assigned rCol1 for CRD_EKSP_PIER_FIN

Comment: Are the data in `rCol` and `rCol3` both formatted as numbers, or are they formatted as strings/text/general?

Comment: @Cyril in inside excel they are 'general' on macro dim as range

Comment: Without having data, I would not be able to troubleshoot; do you have mock-up data to support, that you can add to your post?  Note that giving a link to a downloadable file is a faux pas, so providing data in the post is the better option.  At this point, nothing looks out of the ordinary upon glance, which suggested that the error may be data driving.

Comment: Have you tried this *without* using `rTable`?  You're using `With wbMe.Sheets("NPE")`, and your table range started at `cells(1,1)`, so any column is the column within the sheet.

Comment: @Cyril here on first post you have sample.xlsx https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1370107-vba-sumifs-under-two-conditions.html#post5628754

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241653/discussion-between-przemyslaw-dabek-and-cyril).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to set-up your data:

[image]

Making a change to your code, since:

- `rTable` does not seem necessary at all,
- the `if` statement wrapping your `sumifs()` keeps triggering the `false` state,
- going to put in checks for each column being found (removes ranges, uses column values),
- going to simplify some variables (`rCol` & `rColString` to ensure things match up) and dimensions, and
- i don't want to scroll for numbers, so outputting to `F1`:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rColString As String
    rColString = "DIFFRENT"
    Dim rCol1String As String
    rCol1String = "CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN"
    Dim rCol2String As String
    rCol2String = "CRD_KOR_DC_FIN"
    Dim rCol3String As String
    rCol3String = "CRD_RWG"
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NPE")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        Dim rCol As Long
        rCol = .Rows(1).Find(What:=rColString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        Dim rCol1 As Long
        rCol1 = .Rows(1).Find(What:=rCol1String, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        Dim rCol2 As Long
        rCol2 = .Rows(1).Find(What:=rCol2String, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        Dim rCol3 As Long
        rCol3 = .Rows(1).Find(What:=rCol3String, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        .Range("F1").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Columns(rCol), .Columns(rCol), ">365", .Columns(rCol3), "<1.5", .Columns(rCol1), "CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN", .Columns(rCol2), "CRD_KOR_DC_FIN")
    End With
End Sub
```

After running the modified macro:

[image]

---

One thing that strikes me as odd is that you're searching for the LABEL in each row, for your `sumifs()`, i.e., "CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN" and "CRD_KOR_DC_FIN", so if you have actual values in the columns of the same header, then that would be a place to check.

---

**Edit1:**

Your data suggested that this is incorrect:

```
.Range("F1").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Columns(rCol), .Columns(rCol), ">365", .Columns(rCol3), "<1.5", .Columns(rCol1), "CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN", .Columns(rCol2), "CRD_KOR_DC_FIN")
```

You are checking that the value for each row in `.Columns(rCol1)`  is "CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN", and similarly `.Columns(rCol2)` is  "CRD_KOR_DC_FIN", which neither is true... hence always getting a zero result.  This should work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rColString As String
    rColString = "DIFFRENT"
    Dim rCol1String As String
    rCol1String = "CRD_EKSP_PIER_DC_FIN"
    Dim rCol2String As String
    rCol2String = "CRD_KOR_DC_FIN"
    Dim rCol3String As String
    rCol3String = "CRD_RWG"
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("NPE")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        Dim rCol As Long
        rCol = .Rows(1).Find(What:=rColString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        Dim rCol1 As Long
        rCol1 = .Rows(1).Find(What:=rCol1String, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        Dim rCol2 As Long
        rCol2 = .Rows(1).Find(What:=rCol2String, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        Dim rCol3 As Long
        rCol3 = .Rows(1).Find(What:=rCol3String, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
        .Range("F1").Value = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Columns(rCol), .Columns(rCol), ">365", .Columns(rCol3), "<1.5")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Still not help :.I added what my data looks like in the main post.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that, @PrzemysławDabek .  Your issue is that you're putting a `sumifs()` criteria of the HEADER for each of the rows, like in my example.  You need to remove the criteria related to `rCol1` and `rCol2` like I mentioned in the last paragraph of my post.

Comment: @PrzemysławDabek i've added an edit to my answer, which should resolve your issue of having incorrect criteria in your `sumifs()`.